# No Chrome icon in system tray since update to 70

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, system-tray, notification-area

After update chrome-stable to latest version 70 there is no more Chrome icon in system tray on Ubuntu 16.04 and no convenient way to access installed Chrome Apps.

Any ideas whether it is permanent change from Google or there is a way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

With latest system update the issue gone. As of now I have:

```
Browser: Google Chrome 71.0.3578.80 (WebKit 537.36)
Operating system: Linux 4.15.0-42-generic #45~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 19 13:02:27 UTC
2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```